# Can log-transform to TS reduce forecast accuracy vs non-transformed TS

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, data-transformation, logarithm

I have to apply a SARIMAX model to over 300 TS. Many of them have increasing volatility which can be addressed by aplying log to the TS.

Problem is that also many TSs don't have this problem. Is it ok to apply log to all TS even if they don't need it? Could I be losing accuracy for doing this?

Comment: There is usually no free lunch when it comes to modeling options. It is certainly possible to lose accuracy due to an unwarranted logarithmic transformation.

Comment: How would you measure accuracy any way?

Comment: @RichardHardy What do you mean by *unwarranted*

Comment: I mean it tautologically. If it harms prediction, it is unwarranted for the purpose of prediction.